# Subset rows which have a rowSums of 0

Tags: r

Looking to subset a data frame (all columns numeric) based on a condition. I would like the rows which have a rowSum = 0 to be subsetted. Only able to find a solution to subset the rows which don't equal 0!

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We can use  `subset` with `rowSums`

```
subset(df1, rowSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE) == 0)
```